# PHP ternary operator error

Tags: php, ternary-operator

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP ternary operator not working as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14214427/php-ternary-operator-not-working-as-expected)

I dont know what is wrong with my code? My PHP Version is 5.4.7.

```
$b = 'a';
$c = 'd';
echo $b == 'a' ? 2: $c == 'a' ? 1 : 0; 

output 1
```

right answer should be 2.....

Thank you very much for your advice.

Comment: The **language manual** clearly states: [It is recommended that you avoid "stacking" ternary expressions. PHP's behaviour when using more than one ternary operator within a single statement is non-obvious:](http://us.php.net/ternary#example-121).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to add some parenthesis.

```
$b = 'a';
$c = 'd';
echo ($b == 'a') ? 2 : ($c == 'a' ? 1 : 0);
```

Comment: Thank you very much! May I ask why this will not work in php??

Comment: I mean the way I got wrong, it should be right in js

Comment: The best answer to this was given by @DCoder. I recommend reading his link.