# Why does php ternary operator give wrong output?

Tags: php, ternary-operator, php-7, php-5.6

> I have already seen the thread [PHP ternary operator error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14399745/php-ternary-operator-error)

I have seen the thread mentioned above and am using parenthesis but still it doesn't give the expected output.

```
<?php
    $ch = 'A';
    $ans = (($ch == 'C') ? 'Cccc'
        : ($ch == 'A') ? 'Aaaa'
        : ($ch == 'G') ? 'Ggggg'
        : ($ch == 'Y') ? 'Yyyyy'
        : 'unknown');
    echo $ans;
    echo "\n";
?>
```

This outputs `Yyyyy` and not `Aaaa` as expected. Can anyone explain why ?

Comment: Why don't you just use an associative array instead of a sequence of ternaries?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @Barmar ! I can use an associative array but I was just curious why this is happening

Comment: It's because the ternary operator is left-associative. So it's as if you wrote `((($ch == 'C') ? 'Cccc'
        : ($ch == 'A') ? 'Aaaa'
        : ($ch == 'G') ? 'Ggggg'
        : ($ch == 'Y')) ? 'Yyyyy'
        : 'unknown')`

Answer (score 1):

The braces is not placed right way. Try this

```
$ch = 'A';
    $ans = ($ch == 'C' ? 'Cccc' :
         ($ch == 'A' ? 'Aaaa' :
         ($ch == 'G' ? 'Ggggg' : 
         ($ch == 'Y' ? 'Yyyyy':
         'unknown'))));
    echo $ans;
    echo "\n";
```

Comment: I'm not sure why this was downvoted as it works as intended.